# requests не возвращает то, что возвращает браузер

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Всем добрый день! Мне необходимо извлечь информацию об организации с сайта ФНС ЕГРЮЛ. В инструментах разработчика я нашёл,что для получения иденификатора организации, браузер делает пост запрос с информацией введённой в форму, которая заполняется в параметрах с ключом query. Однако при выполнении кода ниже выдаёт ошибку c сервера {"ERRORS":{"query":["Не заполнено обязательное поле "Поисковый запрос""]}}. Какое может быть решение данной проблеммы?

```
import requests

payloads_ = {'query': '6658068859'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'
                         ' AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
response = requests.post(f"https://egrul.nalog.ru/",
                        params=payloads_, headers = headers)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно заполнять `data`, а не `params`:

- `data` - это тело запроса
- `params` - это параметры в ссылке

```
import requests

payloads_ = {'query': '6658068859'}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)'
                   ' AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                    'Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}
response = requests.post(f"https://egrul.nalog.ru/", data=payloads_, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
# {"t":"0D18CB30BA0077<...>353CC4F633A233811","captchaRequired":false}
```